# Planning for a dual arm robot in MoveIt

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been trying to plan for a dual arm robot ABB YuMi in MoveIt. The package now has a both_arm group and I can plan for this group by 'setPoseTarget()' for two end effectors and 'plan()' for the group. It works well. However, when I try to use 'computeCartesianPath', I realise this function does not allow specifying end effectors. Is there a way to compute trajectories with predefined waypoints for a two arm group?

One way that I could think of was to compute trajectories for separate arm groups and combine the trajectories before execution. However, in this way, collision between two arms would not be taken into consideration, which could be a potential risk.

Any idea is appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: [Here](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/sqPdMPzU) is how I combined the trajectories.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370136/planning-for-a-dual-arm-robot-in-moveit/) by [Henning Luo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39365/henning-luo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2021-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've defined my SRDF like [this](https://github.com/o2as/ur-o2as/blob/master/catkin_ws/src/o2as_moveit_config/config/o2as_base_scene.srdf):

```
<group name="a_bot">
    <joint name="a_bot_shoulder_pan_joint" />
    <joint name="a_bot_shoulder_lift_joint" />
    <joint name="a_bot_elbow_joint" />
    <joint name="a_bot_wrist_1_joint" />
    <joint name="a_bot_wrist_2_joint" />
    <joint name="a_bot_wrist_3_joint" />
    <chain base_link="a_bot_base_link" tip_link="a_bot_gripper_tip_link" />
</group>
<group name="b_bot">
    <joint name="b_bot_shoulder_pan_joint" />
    <joint name="b_bot_shoulder_lift_joint" />
    <joint name="b_bot_elbow_joint" />
    <joint name="b_bot_wrist_1_joint" />
    <joint name="b_bot_wrist_2_joint" />
    <joint name="b_bot_wrist_3_joint" />
    <chain base_link="b_bot_base_link" tip_link="b_bot_robotiq_85_tip_link" />
</group>
<group name="both_bots">
    <group name="a_bot" />
    <group name="b_bot" />
</group>
```

This preserves the end-effector information, so you can set multiple goals like [this](https://github.com/o2as/ur-o2as/blob/master/catkin_ws/src/o2as_examples/src/3_bot_example.cpp):

```
group.setPoseTarget(home1, ee_link_a);  
group.setPoseTarget(targetpose, ee_link_b);
success_plan = group.plan(myplan);
```

But this is for "free" planning, and you asked about cartesian planning with waypoints. I don't think that the current implementation supports this, and what you described (generating a cartesian path for each arm separately, then combining the trajectories) is the most appropriate workaround at the moment.

I don't think that there is a convenience function to check for self-collisions in a given trajectory, but you can make one yourself. Step through each waypoint of your trajectory, set the [RobotState](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/moveit_core/html/classmoveit_1_1core_1_1RobotState.html) of a [PlanningScene](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/moveit_core/html/classplanning__scene_1_1PlanningScene.html) object to the state at that waypoint using [setCurrentState](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/moveit_core/html/classplanning__scene_1_1PlanningScene.html#ac5933a79c998cf358566448dc411c62a), then check collisions with [isStateValid](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/moveit_core/html/classplanning__scene_1_1PlanningScene.html#a9ae31eb392220aa92d26eb45863eff7e) or isStateColliding.

This does not guarantee safety since the states between waypoints are not checked, but with enough padding and a small step size it should be fine.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Henning Luo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39365/henning-luo/) on 2021-01-27**:
Thanks fvd! That is exactly what I had been using! I was able to plan the trajectory by setting `setPoseTarget`, it worked perfectly. My problem is that I want to specify waypoints for the end effectors, this is usually done by `computeCartesianPath`. However, this function do not allow specifying end effectors. What I have been doing now is to use `computeCartesianPath` for each arm groups, merge the trajectories together and execute it with `both_arms` group. However, by executing them simultaneously, there is the potential risk that two trajectories might collide with each other.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-01-27**:
I see, I skipped over that part of your original question. I edited my answer.

**Comment by [Henning Luo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39365/henning-luo/) on 2021-01-27**:
Thank you so much for your answer! I will try to do collision detection as you mentioned!

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-01-27**:
It could be helpful if you shared your code for this. See also [this discussion](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/issues/465) about a new multi-arm MoveIt tutorial.

**Comment by [Henning Luo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39365/henning-luo/) on 2021-01-28**:
Yes of course, I will share it in my OP.

**Comment by [Omar Islam](https://answers.ros.org/users/83566/omar-islam/) on 2021-09-04**:
Can someone please elaborate on how to join trajectories because I joined the joint traj points as vectors but it doesn't seem to execute.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-09-05**:
Please post a separate question about your problem, making sure to include the details.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have developed a solution for this issue, you can check it here: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/3381. This function allows the definition of dual-arm trajectories according to **5 synchronization policies**: both arms start and **finish moving at the same time**, both arms **move independently** (each one at its own target speed), both arms reach a set of **waypoints at the same time** (the transitions between waypoints are smooth and the arms don’t stop between waypoints), **constant distance master-slave** (i.e., just the trajectory of the master arm is specified, and the slave arm moves to keep always a constant relative pose with respect to the master arm), **identical master-slave** (i.e., just the trajectory of the master arm is specified, and the slave arm performs the same cartesian displacements and rotations as the master arm). The function checks possible collisions and retrieves a safe plan. With this function, the user has full control over the path and speed of the arms.

The performance of the five synchronization policies on a SDA10F dual-arm Yaskawa robot can be seen in this video (from minute 3:55): https://youtu.be/DJXKWWmBquM?t=235.

---

Originally posted by [pablomalvido](https://answers.ros.org/users/142719/pablomalvido/) with karma: 41 on 2023-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2